# A type of response or humor where the answer is a deliberate mismatch to the question

Tags: expressions

Person A (PA) makes a heart and gives it to Person B (PB). PB accepts and says "thank you" and has no obvious intention to make a heart for PA. PA says " where's my heart?" PB responds with "in your chest" even though PB knew what they actually meant.

Comment: Perhaps "over-literal"

Comment: What does the trailing "vv" in your question's title mean?

Comment: @Lawrence ... I think that's pointing down to the question.

Comment: @jimm101 Oh, that makes sense now, thank you. I thought it was their initials - but that would be TV. I'll edit to delete the extra letters.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "Sarcastic" reply, and Sarcasm is a humorous response.

If PA and PB are good friends, a sarcastic reply where PB intentionally avoids the question, by avoiding it PB answers wrong intentionally with a sarcastic remark stating the obvious.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sarcasm

From the dictionary:

"the use of remarks that clearly mean the opposite of what they say, made in order to hurt someone's feelings or to criticize something in a humorous way"

Example:
"You have been working hard," he said with heavy sarcasm, as he looked at the empty page."

Comment: PB wasn't being sarcastic because your heart is usually in your chest ergo his statement is correct.

Comment: The question from PA is directly related to and connected with getting a gift from PB - continuing on the thread and following the path of a conversation between two people the direct relation to the question that occurs directly after must be assumed connected with the heart received as a gift. Not where the placement of the internal organ is.

In addition, avoiding a question. Where you do not know what to say, you replace your lacking answer with humor and cover over the original question by shifting focus to another topic. In this case where the organ is located.

Comment: Additionally the original post clearly states: "even though PB knew what they actually meant"